# The request JSON is not well formed

Tags: python, json, api, rest, paypal

I'm trying to re-create the example available on this [page](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/make-your-first-call/)

Of course I'm changing the client_id, secret, credit card etc... with my valid data (I haven't copy-pasted the example as is).

You can see my complete code [here](http://pastebin.com/Js2YFDb1) (I've hidden sensible data with ********* ).

I can get the token without any problem, but when I post the payment request I get this back:

```
In [11]: r2.text
Out[11]: u'{"name":"MALFORMED_REQUEST","message":"The request JSON is not well formed.","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#MALFORMED_REQUEST","debug_id":"*************"}'
```

I really can't understand why it says that my json is malformed :(
Anyone can help me? Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason you're trying to do this manually instead of using [the PayPal SDK](https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-python)?

Comment: Also, why are you building `s` as a JSON string manually just to parse it, instead of just creating a dict in the first place?

Comment: @abarnert, it doesn't matter if he has a reason to do it manually. He can learn how to use requests library properly from our answers. However +1 for providing out of box solution for interacting with PayPal.

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo: Sure, learning how to use `requests`, how to talk to web services manually, etc. would all be valid answers to my comment.

Comment: @abarnert, as I said, your comment is very useful. It is good to know about PayPal SDK. However the problem here is titled "The request JSON is not well formed". Later on, Andrea may have to talk to webservice without SDK and knowledge of requests will be essential. For now, I agree, he can and possibly should use PayPal SDK.

Comment: @abarnet yes there is a good reason: PayPal SDK is not available for Python. Only the new REST API has a client for Python. The old one doesn't.

Answer (score 7):

This is your code:

```
post_data = json.loads(s)

r2 = requests.post('https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment', headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token}, 
    data = post_data)
```

You have a JSON string `s` that you convert to a Python object and post that to the server. As [the docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart.html#more-complicated-post-requests) say, if you pass a `dict` as your `data`, it gets form-encoded, not JSON-encoded. If you want data in any other format, you're supposed to encode it yourself, as in the example:

```
>>> r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload))
```

Since you already have the JSON-encoded string `s`, you can just send that.

Comment: It doesn't actually call `str`, it form-encodes the data. I edited the answer to clear that up. Otherwise, it's all correct, and a great answer.

Answer (score 2):

You totally misunderstood what you should pass to `requests.post()` method. http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart.html#more-complicated-post-requests

You are trying to pass Python objects instead of JSON. @Janne's answer is an option, but it is more convenient to build data as Python object and then use `json.dumps(obj)` and pass result to `requests.post()`.

Comment: Do I always have to beg for comments from people who downvote the answer? Constructive critics is good - it gives an opportunity to learn.

Comment: Recently, I've been seeing a lot more downvotes without comments, and it annoys me. And you almost never get comments when you ask for them. (You do usually get 2-5 upvotes if the answer's any good, but as you say, I care more about constructive criticism than about rep points.)